# Mapping whole entity via related tables on EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, foreign-key-relationship

I have a project that has a crowded entity model. Most of the tables are related to each other (one to many, many to many and many to one). I need to get all table names related to each other.

With the code below, I can get all props of a class and eliminate the types by Split method to get other tables related to that class.

```
List<string> tabloIsimleri = new List<string>();
public object GetTableList()
    {            
        var List = dbContext.Takips.ToList();

        foreach (var item in List)
        {
            foreach (_PropertyInfo p in typeof(Takips).GetProperties())
            {
                var propName = p.PropertyType.FullName;

                if (propName.Contains("ProjectName.DataService"))
                {
                    string[] test = p.Name.Split(' ');
                    int a = test.Count();
                    var son = test[a - 1];
                    if (!tabloIsimleri.Contains(son))
                    {
                        tabloIsimleri.Add(son);
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }

        return tabloIsimleri;
    }
```

This method brings back all tables related with "Takips". Apart from doing this manually for all of the tables, how can I reach all related ones?

Let's say I create a new `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and set the keys as the table names, and populate the `List<string>` with table names related to the table which is set as the key. By this way I may hold all of them. However, I could not plan the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed it. Here, how it's done:

```
public class ReportService
{
    EntityName dbContext = new EntityName();

    List<string> tabloIsimleri = new List<string>();
    List<string> tabloListesi = new List<string>();
    List<string> iliskiliOlanlar = new List<string>();
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> agacGosterim = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();


    public void Test()
    {
        try
        {
            tabloListesi = Tablolar();
            string tutmac;
            foreach (var t in tabloListesi)
            {
                tutmac = string.Format("ProjectName.DataService.{0}", t);
                var tip = Type.GetType(tutmac, true);

                foreach (_PropertyInfo p in tip.GetProperties())
                {
                    var propName = p.PropertyType.FullName;

                    if (propName.Contains("ProjectName.DataService"))
                    {
                        string[] test = p.Name.Split(' ');
                        int a = test.Count();
                        var son = test[a - 1];
                        if (!iliskiliOlanlar.Contains(son))
                        {
                            iliskiliOlanlar.Add(son);
                        }
                    }
                }
                agacGosterim.Add(t, iliskiliOlanlar);
                iliskiliOlanlar = new List<string>();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
    public List<string> Tablolar()
    {
        using (var context = new EntityName())
        {
            var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
            var storageMetadata = ((EntityConnection)objectContext.Connection).GetMetadataWorkspace().GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace);
            var entityProps = (from s in storageMetadata where s.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType select s as EntityType);
            foreach (var item in entityProps)
            {
                string[] ayir = item.FullName.Split('.');
                int a = ayir.Count() - 1;
                if (!tabloIsimleri.Contains(ayir[a]))
                {
                    tabloIsimleri.Add(ayir[a]);
                }
            }
            return tabloIsimleri;
        }

    }

}
```